# REST query: $filter by AllProperties of _api/web/webs

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there any way to query subsites via REST and include *$filter* for properties in SPWeb's property bag, like this:

```
http://site.company.com/workspaces/_api/web/webs?$expand=AllProperties&$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl,AllProperties/WorkspaceType&$filter=(AllProperties/WorkspaceType eq 'IT')
```

So I've created SPWeb, added **WorkspaceType** property with value **IT** in the AllProperties of the SPWeb, and would like to list all SPWebs under the */workspaces* site that have a specific value in the *WorkspaceType* property.

Omitting the $filter does return the subwebs fine, including that specific property.

Comment: If you run this request, what does it return? A 400?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that filtering by specific properties in the property bag is not possible. I can think of two possible ways to work around that limitation:

1. Do the filtering in code after fetching all the subwebs.
2. Use Search and [Indexed Properties](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/searching-property-bags-in-sharepoint-2013/) instead of the Webs API endpoint